# Why do we need the Dirac's hole picture?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, second-quantization

When I have to quantize a Dirac field I have to start by the usual classical Lagrangian and find the associated Lagrange equations, then quantize the solutions promoting them to quantum operators. In particular it's known that the field operator can be expressed as
$$\hat{\psi}(\stackrel{\rightarrow}{x},t)=\sum_{r=1}^{4}∫ d^{3}p\hat{a}_{p,r}\psi^{(r)}_{p}(\stackrel{\rightarrow}{x},t)$$
$$\{\hat{a}_{\stackrel{\rightarrow}{p},r},\hat{a}_{\stackrel{\rightarrow}{p}',r'}\}=\{\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{\stackrel{\rightarrow}{p},r},\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{\stackrel{\rightarrow}{p}',r'}\}=0\hspace{0.5cm}\{\hat{a}_{\stackrel{\rightarrow}{p},r},\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{\stackrel{\rightarrow}{p}',r'}\}=δ_{r,r'}δ^{3}(\stackrel{\rightarrow}{p}-\stackrel{\rightarrow}{p}')$$
In this way the quantized Hamiltonian read ($\beta\equiv\gamma^{0},\stackrel{\rightarrow}{\alpha}\equiv\gamma^{0}\stackrel{\rightarrow}{\gamma}$)
$$\hat{H}=∫ d^{3}x\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\stackrel{\rightarrow}{x},t)(-i\stackrel{\rightarrow}{\alpha}\cdot\stackrel{\rightarrow}{\nabla}+\beta m)\hat{\psi}(\stackrel{\rightarrow}{x},t)=...=∫ d^{3}p\biggl(\sum_{r=1}^{2}ω_{p}\hat{n}_{p,r}-\sum_{r=3}^{4}ω_{p}\hat{n}_{p,r}\biggr)$$
At this point is usually said that "as the number of particles in the lower continuum grows, the expectation value oh $\hat{H}$ can drop to negative values beyond any bound". So to avoid this conclusion one has to adopt the Dirac's hole picture that we all know.

My question is:- Can someone explain in more detail this problem?I don't understand very well the physics here... The picture I have in mind is a system of fermions which can acquire negative values of energy, so if I put more and more particles with those energies I get a total amount that is of course negative. Why is it in contrast with experiments? Maybe an example could help.

Comment: I forgot the details, but positivity of H is a sufficient condition for Fermion Statistics. So it's most likely that you made a mistake in derivation of the H you present.

Comment: That statement is itself wrong. Dirac's sea of filled electrons and exciting a hole in them is a dead end. Instead, QFT is what is needed, that you need to consider positrons, so that the energies are counted as positive. The problem is that if you have a Hamiltonian that can be arbitrarily large in the negatives, then the usual physics notion of systems preferring to settle into ground states will just produce infinitely many holes in this Hamiltonian, and that cannot be meaningfully dealt with.

Comment: Ok so there could be no stable configuration? Makes sense